# Java User Input array is only capturing 3 integers instead of five

Tags: java, arrays

This code is supposed to capture 5 user integers, print them out, then print them in reverse. It is capturing the first int only, and printing it 3 times, then printing the first integer again 5 more times without reversing. Test ends with "Process finished with exit code 0"  which I think is says the program finished without errors -- which of course is not correct. I assume the issue is in how the user input array is stored. I have it assigning as userNum[i] with a limited array of 5, and int i =0 to begin array storage at userNum[0], so I'm not clear on why all the inputs are not captured up to userNum[4].
Thank you for any insight you can provide. I am very new to java and this is prework for my java class.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ArrayReverse {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in); // scanner for input
        final int NUM_VALS = 5; // number on int user able to enter
        int[] userNum = new int[NUM_VALS]; // user integers storage
        int j = 0;
        int i = 0;

        System.out.println("Enter integer values: ");
        userNum[i] = scnr.nextInt(); // capture user input int

        for (j = 0; j < NUM_VALS; j++) {
            System.out.print("You entered: ");
            System.out.println(userNum[i]);
            ++j;
        }
        System.out.print("\nNumbers in reverse: "); // statement to Print reversed array
        for (j = NUM_VALS - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
            System.out.print(userNum[i] + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm confused why it even enters more than one since `i = 0` and you never change it.

Comment: Any reason why you increment j inside the for?

Comment: this is the test:   Enter integer values: 
6 8 9 2 4 7 5 4
You entered: 6
You entered: 6
You entered: 6

Numbers in reverse: 6 6 6 6 6 
Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: I tried j to see if there was an conflict with the reversing and capturing the userNum

Comment: You only enter a single number. `i` is always 0. You only print `userNum[i]`, which is `userNum[0]`, which is always whatever you entered first.

Comment: @StefanFreitag when I used i in the for, I got this error: Enter integer values: 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 
You entered: 1
You entered: 0
You entered: 0

Numbers in reverse: 0 0 0 0 1 
Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: @DaveNewton okay - when I used only the single i = 0 I get the error: Enter integer values: 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 
You entered: 1
You entered: 0
You entered: 0

Numbers in reverse: 0 0 0 0 1 
Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: You're incrementing twice inside your first loop using j++. This was the reason you are skipping elements from the array when printing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution using the collections framework:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ArrayReverse {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in); // scanner for input
    final List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
    System.out.println("Enter any number of integers. (whitespace delimited. enter a non-integer to quit.): ");
    while (scnr.hasNextBigInteger()) {
      final int n = scnr.nextInt();
      System.out.println("Parsed: " + n);
      numbers.add(n);
    }
    System.out.println("Done reading user input.");
    System.out.println("Your input: " + numbers);
    Collections.reverse(numbers);
    System.out.println("Your input reversed: " + numbers);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Andreas

Answer (score 1):

You need to work more about on for loops and study how to iterate values in for loop, the problem in your i,j variables.

Here I fix your code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ArrayReverse {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in); // scanner for input
    final int NUM_VALS = 5;  // number on int user able to enter
    int[] userNum = new int[NUM_VALS]; // user integers storage
    int j = 0;
    int i = 0;
   //for 5 inputs you need loop
   for(;i<NUM_VALS;i++){
    System.out.println("Enter integer values: ");
        userNum[i] = scnr.nextInt(); // capture user input int
   }

    for (j = 0; j < NUM_VALS; j++) {
        System.out.print("You entered: ");
        System.out.println(userNum[j]);
        //++j; //no need to increment as you already did in for loop
    }
    System.out.print("\nNumbers in reverse: "); // statement to Print reversed array
    for (j = NUM_VALS - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
        System.out.print(userNum[j] + " ");// userNum[0] = your last value which you reverse 
    }


}
}
```

Comment: Perhaps *explaining* what you did would be more beneficial than just doing the OP's homework.

Comment: @Omore Thank you.  This correction still print three "Enter integer values: ", and the first three userNum "You entered:"  -- I'm not clear why not all five userNum are not printing. The reverse order prints correctly now however.

Comment: @L.Lab1 this code is working fine and getting 5 inputs and print each input and also print in reverse order, try to clean your project if you are using mine code. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have provided you with a solution. This is a clean way of doing it.
`nextInt()` reads the next integer that the user inputs. Notice that this will throw a `InputMismatchException`if the user does not input a integer as value.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    List<Integer> input = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    //Simple loop that will read 5 user inputs
    //and add them to the input list
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        input.add(scanner.nextInt());
    }

    //print the 5 values
    for(Integer val : input){
        System.out.println(val);
    }

    //reverse the 5 values
    Collections.reverse(input);

    //print the 5 values again, but they are now reversed
    for(Integer val : input){
        System.out.println(val);
    }
}
```